# document.head.appendchild dosen't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, dom, browser

I found below code.
it worked very well. BUT I found that it doesn't work on mobile.
and I know that `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild` this code is problem... mobile browser dosen't allow to use that code. 
so usually people use `document.head`.

so I changed code `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild` into `document.head.appendChild`. But it still doesn't work on mobile.

What Should I do?

```
 function detectIE() {
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
    var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');

    if (msie > 0) {
        // IE 10 or older => return version number
        alert("ie10 or older");
        var ss = document.createElement("link");
        ss.type = "text/css";
        ss.rel = "stylesheet";
        ss.href = "css/ie9font.css";
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(ss);
        return false;
    }

    if (trident > 0) {
        // IE 11 (or newer) => return version number
        var rv = ua.indexOf('rv:');
        alert("ie11");
        var ss = document.createElement("link");
        ss.type = "text/css";
        ss.rel = "stylesheet";
        ss.href = "css/ie9font.css";
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(ss);
        return false;
    }

    // other browser
    var rv = ua.indexOf('rv:');
    alert("other");
    var ss = document.createElement("link");
    ss.type = "text/css";
    ss.rel = "stylesheet";
    ss.href = "css/font.css";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(ss);
    return false;
}
detectIE();
```

it worked very well. BUT I found that it doesn't work on mobile.
and I know that `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild` this code is problem... mobile browser dosen't allow to use that code. 
so usually people use 'document.head'.

so I changed code `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild` into `document.head'.appendChild`. But it still doesn't work on mobile.

What Should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used:

```
var head = document.head || document.documentElement.childNodes[0];
```

...and it have worked in my cases (mobile). Of course assuming that **head** element follows **html** element directly.